# How to find a string contained in an array?

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays:

- $DatesToDelete()
- $ArrayAllDates()

$DatesToDelete() contains a list of dates, like this:

01/11/2022
02/11/2022
03/11/2022
04/11/2022
05/11/2022
06/11/2022
07/11/2022
08/11/2022
09/11/2022
10/11/2022
11/11/2022
12/11/2022
13/11/2022
14/11/2022
15/11/2022
16/11/2022
17/11/2022
18/11/2022
19/11/2022
20/11/2022
21/11/2022
22/11/2022
23/11/2022
24/11/2022
25/11/2022
26/11/2022
27/11/2022
28/11/2022
29/11/2022
30/11/2022

$ArrayAllDates() contains another list of dates, like this:

07/11/2022
07/11/2022
18/11/2022
17/11/2022
02/12/2022

**My goal is to find if dates coming from $DatesToDelete() are contained in $ArrayAllDates()
**

I'm not a PHP expert and I tried a lot of loops with foreach() without success :-(

Thank you

```
foreach($ArrayAllDates as $d) {
    foreach($DatesToDelete as $e) {
       if(in_array($b,$arrayalldates)){
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also simply use `$arrayMatchingDates = array_intersect($ArrayAllDates, $DatesToDelete);` it will give you all matching dates which is present in the `$ArrayAllDates` from the `$DatesToDelete`

Comment: I asked another related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651932/how-to-find-a-date-that-is-not-contained-in-an-array Maybe you can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@DCodeMania](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8546303/dcodemania) said, you can use the array_intersect function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

For example:

```
$datesToDelete = [
    '02/11/2022',
    '04/11/2022',
    '06/11/2022',
    '07/11/2022',
    '02/12/2022',
];
$allDates = [
    '07/11/2022',
    '07/11/2022',
    '18/11/2022',
    '17/11/2022',
    '02/12/2022',
];
$commonDates = array_intersect($allDates, $datesToDelete);
print_r($commonDates);
/* it print this:
Array
(
    [0] => 07/11/2022
    [1] => 07/11/2022
    [4] => 02/12/2022
)
when the key is de key and value are of $allDates array
*/
```

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: I asked another related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651932/how-to-find-a-date-that-is-not-contained-in-an-array Maybe you can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this looping

```
foreach($ArrayAllDates as $d){
  if(in_array($d, $DatesToDelete)){
    echo $d."<br>";
  }
}
```

if you want save this contain date to array

```
$containDates = array();
foreach($ArrayAllDates as $d){
  if(in_array($d, $DatesToDelete)){
    array_push($containDates ,$d);
  }
}
print_r($containDates);
```

Comment: I asked another related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651932/how-to-find-a-date-that-is-not-contained-in-an-array Maybe you can help me? Thanks