# How to find a date that is not contained in an array

Tags: php

I have an array: $data()

This array containes lines like:

- 0cfed22b-b07b-4ef2-8469-ac801a18c55f BU-BOURHIS 1c651143-0bb8-43c7-8cc6-081e2d6cd1a5 07/11/2022 14:00:00
- fe66729f-00d1-4e57-bee4-8c291884bf86 BU-BOURHIS aa1b7f8f-3771-4333-870e-306d16bed469 07/11/2022 18:00:00
- d7b09279-2702-4f55-b133-4d283967fc34 DEM 7c705523-4528-4ab1-a023-bb29ab6f988c 18/11/2022 19:00:00
- 083f22a7-ed62-40cc-9fd4-7d4a5ca374d1 DEM 39962e32-f1f0-494f-a4b6-0fba47d80e49 17/11/2022 10:00:00
- 8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0 04/12/2022 14:00:00

I have another array: $DatesToDelete()

This array containes lines like:

- 02/11/2022
- 03/11/2022
- 04/11/2022
- 05/11/2022
- 06/11/2022
- 07/11/2022
- 08/11/2022
- 09/11/2022
- 10/11/2022
- 11/11/2022
- 12/11/2022
- 13/11/2022
- 14/11/2022
- 15/11/2022
- 16/11/2022
- 16/11/2022
- 17/11/2022
- 18/11/2022
- 19/11/2022
- 20/11/2022
- 21/11/2022
- 22/11/2022
- 23/11/2022
- 24/11/2022
- 25/11/2022
- 26/11/2022
- 27/11/2022
- 28/11/2022
- 29/11/2022
- 30/11/2022
- 01/12/2022
- 02/12/2022
- 03/12/2022

What I would like to do is to find in the array $data() the lines that contains dates that are not contained in the array $DatesToDelete().

In my exemple the line:

8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0 04/12/2022 14:00:00

contains the date 04/12/2022, so the expected result should be :

8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0 04/12/2022 14:00:00

because the date 04/12/2022 is not contained in any lines of the array $DatesToDelete()

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not ment to do your job. We help you with concrete questions with your code. So show us some code.

Comment: Hi Marcel, I'm not a developper at all :-( I tried some loops with foreach() that do not works... and it's not my job ^^

I edited my question to be more clear.

Thanks

Comment: You can use explode on spaces in the string to get the date ie ```$boom = explode( ' ', $data );``` as you have a string in the following format {uuid} {3 letters} {uuid} {date} {time} then you are after the 3rd element of the resulting array. you can then use ``` in_array( $datestoDelete, $boom[3]) in an if statement. Hope that helps to guide you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the date formats in these two arrays are slightly different a quick comparison of the two was made slightly more complicated. By formatting them both with the same, conventional date format it is then possible to do `array_diff` to find the differences.

Because the desired result also includes the date & times in original format a copy of the original `$data` array was kept to process in the final stage.

```
$data=array(
    '0cfed22b-b07b-4ef2-8469-ac801a18c55f BU-BOURHIS 1c651143-0bb8-43c7-8cc6-081e2d6cd1a5'=>'07/11/2022 14:00:00',
    'fe66729f-00d1-4e57-bee4-8c291884bf86 BU-BOURHIS aa1b7f8f-3771-4333-870e-306d16bed469'=>'07/11/2022 18:00:00',
    'd7b09279-2702-4f55-b133-4d283967fc34 DEM 7c705523-4528-4ab1-a023-bb29ab6f988c'=>'18/11/2022 19:00:00',
    '083f22a7-ed62-40cc-9fd4-7d4a5ca374d1 DEM 39962e32-f1f0-494f-a4b6-0fba47d80e49'=>'17/11/2022 10:00:00',
    '8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0'=>'04/12/2022 14:00:00'
);
# copy the original array for later
$original=$data;

# final output
$output=array();

$dates=array(#DatesToDelete
    '02/11/2022',
    '03/11/2022',
    '04/11/2022',
    '05/11/2022',
    '06/11/2022',
    '07/11/2022',
    '08/11/2022',
    '09/11/2022',
    '10/11/2022',
    '11/11/2022',
    '12/11/2022',
    '13/11/2022',
    '14/11/2022',
    '15/11/2022',
    '16/11/2022'
);
/*
    process the date values into usable format - remove times
    so they are all in a consistent format.
*/
array_walk( $data, function(&$v,$k){
    $v=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $v )->format('Y-m-d');
});
array_walk( $dates, function(&$v,$k){
    $v=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $v )->format('Y-m-d');
});
/*
    compute the difference between these modified arrays
*/
$result=array_diff( $data, $dates );
/* 
    Now find the original key/values including the times which 
    were stripped previously to allow comparison earlier.
*/
array_walk( $result,function($v,$k){
    global $output;
    global $original;
    if( in_array( $k, array_keys( $original ) ) )$output[$k]=$original[$k];
});
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($output,true));
```

The above yields:

```
Array
(
    [d7b09279-2702-4f55-b133-4d283967fc34 DEM 7c705523-4528-4ab1-a023-bb29ab6f988c] => 18/11/2022 19:00:00
    [083f22a7-ed62-40cc-9fd4-7d4a5ca374d1 DEM 39962e32-f1f0-494f-a4b6-0fba47d80e49] => 17/11/2022 10:00:00
    [8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0] => 04/12/2022 14:00:00
)
```

**update**
IF the source array `$data` contains only strings rather than key / value pairs as assumed above an additional task should be performed on that array initially during the first `array_walk` call. The individual strings will be split by space character and the `DateTime::createFromFormat` call is then based upon the `date` portion of the string itself rather than date/time as previously assumed.

```
$data=array(
    '0cfed22b-b07b-4ef2-8469-ac801a18c55f BU-BOURHIS 1c651143-0bb8-43c7-8cc6-081e2d6cd1a5 07/11/2022 14:00:00',
    'fe66729f-00d1-4e57-bee4-8c291884bf86 BU-BOURHIS aa1b7f8f-3771-4333-870e-306d16bed469 07/11/2022 18:00:00',
    'd7b09279-2702-4f55-b133-4d283967fc34 DEM 7c705523-4528-4ab1-a023-bb29ab6f988c 18/11/2022 19:00:00',
    '083f22a7-ed62-40cc-9fd4-7d4a5ca374d1 DEM 39962e32-f1f0-494f-a4b6-0fba47d80e49 17/11/2022 10:00:00',
    '8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0 04/12/2022 14:00:00'
);

# copy the original array for later
$original=$data;

# final output
$output=array();

#DatesToDelete
$dates=array(
    '02/11/2022',
    '03/11/2022',
    '04/11/2022',
    '05/11/2022',
    '06/11/2022',
    '07/11/2022',
    '08/11/2022',
    '09/11/2022',
    '10/11/2022',
    '11/11/2022',
    '12/11/2022',
    '13/11/2022',
    '14/11/2022',
    '15/11/2022',
    '16/11/2022'
);

array_walk( $data, function(&$item,$key){
    list( $h1, $code, $h2, $ds, $ts )=explode(' ', $item );
    $item=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $ds )->format('Y-m-d');
});
array_walk( $dates, function(&$v,$k){
    $v=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $v )->format('Y-m-d');
});

#compute the differnce between these modified arrays
$result=array_diff( $data, $dates );

array_walk( $result,function($v,$k){
    global $output;
    global $original;
    if( in_array( $k, array_keys( $original ) ) )$output[$k]=$original[$k];
});
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($output,true));
```

This revised version yields:

```
Array
(
    [2] => d7b09279-2702-4f55-b133-4d283967fc34 DEM 7c705523-4528-4ab1-a023-bb29ab6f988c 18/11/2022 19:00:00
    [3] => 083f22a7-ed62-40cc-9fd4-7d4a5ca374d1 DEM 39962e32-f1f0-494f-a4b6-0fba47d80e49 17/11/2022 10:00:00
    [4] => 8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0 04/12/2022 14:00:00
)
```

Comment: Hi and thank you but I tried your code, the result is not what I want... The result should be "8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0 04/12/2022 14:00:00"

Comment: Perhaps you can add the actual arrays rather than what you posted. Are you suggesting that the entire strings from `$data` are the values only and not key/value pairs as I (perhaps wrongly) assumed?

Comment: $DatesToDelete() = 02/11/2022
03/11/2022
04/11/2022
05/11/2022
06/11/2022
07/11/2022
08/11/2022
09/11/2022
10/11/2022
11/11/2022
12/11/2022
13/11/2022
14/11/2022
15/11/2022
16/11/2022
17/11/2022
18/11/2022
19/11/2022
20/11/2022
21/11/2022
22/11/2022
23/11/2022
24/11/2022
25/11/2022
26/11/2022
27/11/2022
28/11/2022
29/11/2022
30/11/2022
01/12/2022
02/12/2022 *** $data() is the same I posted

Comment: so, each item in the array `$data`  (ie: `0cfed22b-b07b-4ef2-8469-ac801a18c55f BU-BOURHIS 1c651143-0bb8-43c7-8cc6-081e2d6cd1a5 07/11/2022 14:00:00` ) are values **only** and not key/value where the date is the value ?

Comment: I don't know what are "values only and not key/value "... Sorry But I'm French and it's hard for me :-( But my goal in only to get '8e1eaeef-9985-4e06-b75a-3d1c0cc6808b NOT 05213f71-8deb-4aef-9195-41e162da15e0 04/12/2022 14:00:00' because in this, there is a date: '04/12/2022' that is NOT contained in the array $data(). Hope this is more clear. Thanks

Comment: `17/11/2022` and `18/11/2022` - neither are in the `$dates` array either - at least not in what you originally posted. My revised code does do what you want I believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250110/discussion-between-pascal-and-professor-abronsius).